# Data Subset by Date based on Criteria in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 2 columns and several rows, with a repeated ID in one column, and several dates on the other. How can I create a subset of data with the first two records by ID?

- **- ID       Date**

  - A  1/1/18 18:34
  - A  1/1/18 18:35
  - A  1/1/18 18:35
  - A  1/1/18 18:36
  - A  1/1/18 18:37
  - A  1/1/18 18:38
  - A  1/1/18 18:39
  - B  1/1/18 18:34
  - B  1/1/18 18:35
  - B  1/1/18 18:35
  - B  1/1/18 18:36
  - B  1/1/18 18:37
  - B  1/1/18 18:38
  - B  1/1/18 18:39
  - C  1/1/18 18:34
  - C  1/1/18 18:35
  - C  1/1/18 18:36
  - C  1/1/18 18:36
  - C  1/1/18 18:36
  - C  1/1/18 18:37
  - C  1/1/18 18:38

Expected Result:

> - **ID   Date**
>
>   - A    1/1/18 18:34
>   - A    1/1/18 18:35
>   - B    1/1/18 18:34
>   - B    1/1/18 18:35
>   - C    1/1/18 18:34
>   - C    1/1/18 18:35

Answer (score 0):

You can create a field that sequentially counts the records by ID and Date using the `data.table` package, like so:

```
data <- data[, count := sequence(.N), by = c('ID', 'Date')][]
```

Then, you can subset the data based on `count`:

```
result <- subset(data, count <= 2)
```

Comment: Thanks Erik, I get this error:
Error in `[.data.frame`(CSV_Source_File, , `:=`(count, sequence(.N)),  : 
  unused argument (by = c('ID', 'Date'))[]

Comment: Looks like you have a syntax issue - can you post your entire line of code that throws the error?

Comment: Also, make sure you install and require the `data.table` package.

Comment: Sure, this is what I'm using:
Data <- CSV_Source_File[, count := sequence(.N), by = c('ID', 'Date', 'Code','Description', 'Event.Name')][]

Comment: With data.table, you'd do `data[, head(.SD, 2), by=.(ID, Date)]`

Answer (score 0):

I edit this post in order to clarify the approach. This snippet consists in a `group by` according the column `ID` followed by the `head` function over the `dates` column, which retrieves the first two instances for each different `ID`. Let's say that the dates are in the format:

```
dates = c('Date 1 A', 'Date 2 A', 'Date 3 A', 'Date 4 A', 'Date 5 A', 'Date 6 A', 'Date 7 A',
          'Date 1 B', 'Date 2 B', 'Date 3 B', 'Date 4 B', 'Date 5 B', 'Date 6 B', 'Date 7 B',
          'Date 1 C', 'Date 2 C', 'Date 3 c', 'Date 4 c', 'Date 5 c', 'Date 6 c', 'Date 7 c')
```

So we have 7 different dates for each `ID` (A, B and C) and these dates are tagged with the corresponding `ID`. **I also assume the dataset is ordered by `ID` and `dates`.**

Now, grouping by `ID` and using `head(<columnwewanttosubset>, 2)`

```
ID <- rep(c('A','B','C'), c(7,7,7))

df <- data.table(ID,dates)

df[, .(Dates = head(dates,2)), by = ID]

#    ID    Dates
# 1:  A Date 1 A
# 2:  A Date 2 A
# 3:  B Date 1 B
# 4:  B Date 2 B
# 5:  C Date 1 C
# 6:  C Date 2 C
```

So, as you can see the output are the first two `dates` for each different `ID`.

**EDITED** *(See above this line)*

I would recommend `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

dates <- c('1/1/18 18:34','1/1/18 18:35','1/1/18 18:35','1/1/18 18:36','1/1/18 18:37','1/1/18 18:38','1/1/18 18:39','1/1/18 18:34','1/1/18 18:35','1/1/18 18:35','1/1/18 18:36','1/1/18 18:37','1/1/18 18:38','1/1/18 18:39','1/1/18 18:34','1/1/18 18:35','1/1/18 18:36','1/1/18 18:36','1/1/18 18:36','1/1/18 18:37','1/1/18 18:38')
ID <- rep(c('A','B','C'), c(7,7,7))

df <- data.table(ID,dates)

df[,head(dates,2), by = ID]

#    ID           V1
# 1:  A 1/1/18 18:34
# 2:  A 1/1/18 18:35
# 3:  B 1/1/18 18:34
# 4:  B 1/1/18 18:35
# 5:  C 1/1/18 18:34
# 6:  C 1/1/18 18:35
```

Comment: The thing is that the first two date/times are different for each ID, so you can't sub set using values.

Comment: I don't get your point. This is just retrieving the first two instances for each group (defined in the `by`). Try using 4 instead of 2, you will get the first 4 instances for each different group.

Comment: On dates, you are subseting by dates, but in my data I have different dates for each ID, what I need is to pull the first 2 instances for each ID

Comment: Hi @DanielAlmaraz, please, see the edited post. I believe this is exactly what you are looking for. If this is not the case, please provide with a different example and I will try to help you.